# Van't Hoff graph, the Ka is increasing at a slower rate as temperature increases

Tags: equilibrium

[image]
I understand the exponential relationship between Ka and temperature, but I had expected it to be curving upwards(because of the $e^x$), and not like a log graph (where y-values increases slower for every increse in x-values). Can someone verify if this graph is legit? This graph is Ka(y-axis) against temperature in Kelvin (x-axis). I have isolated for $K(T_2)$ in the Van't Hoff Equation.

I did an experiment on the Ka values of acetic acid, and when I graphed it out, it was curving upwards like a parabola. Can someone help explain the inconsistencies between the theoretical and experimental data?

Comment: Your expectations do not consider the differential form of the equation d(ln k)/dT=(Delta H)/(RT^2).dT where the slope explicitly decreases with T due 1/T^2. // Note that due semilogarithmic nature of the chart, the vertical axis is geometrically for ln K, in spite of being for K numerically .

Comment: But my experiment's graph was also Ka against temperature

Comment: Note the 2nd part of my comment.

Comment: Because I wish to find the theoretical Ka values at different tempeatures, I have rearranged the Van't Hoff equation.

Comment: By other words, the chart is exactly as expected.

Comment: Yes, I acknowledge the y-axis of the Van't Hoff equation being ln(K). However, is there a possibility of only wanting Ka against Temperature?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150601/discussion-between-poutnik-and-metron).